# Turns all the char words in the opposite way using getline, array in c++

Tags: c++

```
char reversevirkne(char virkne[]) {
    int apgriests, x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; virkne[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        x++;
    }
    x--;
    for (int j = x; j >= 0; j--) {
        apgriests = (int)virkne[j];
        std::cout << virkne[j];
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program turns all of the sentence to the opposite way. I need it to turn only the words so they would stay in there positions.
example:

- input: `hello world`
- output: `olleh dlrow`

Comment: You can try ways to first convert the string to array of string(each string representing a word) and reverse each word.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Usage of `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::istringstream`, and `std::reverse` makes this whole thing a program that is less than 10 lines or so.  The question to you is do you want to see that implementation as an answer?

Comment: "I need code" questions often are not viewed highly.  Have you tried to write this?  Are you stuck somewhere?  Do you have a specific question about what you're attempting?

Comment: `apgriests = (int)virkne[j];` has several problems. 1) apgriests is never used. 2) casting should be avoided and there is no need for it here.

Answer (score 1):

This really not complicated to do :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reversevirkne(const char virkne[]) {
  std::string w;

  for (int i = 0; virkne[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (virkne[i] > ' ') // test also manages \t
      w = virkne[i] + w;
    else if (!w.empty()) {
      std::cout << w << ' ';
      w.clear();
    }
  }

  std::cout << w << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
  reversevirkne("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```