# How to output each word in a char array backwards

Tags: c++

I have to make a function which reverses words that have been written in an char array.

```
char reverse(char m[50]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= m['\0']; i++) {
        for (int j = m['\0']-1; j >= m[0]; j--) {
            m[i] = m[j];
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have in mind which would output something like this:

Input: `I am new`
Output: `wen ma I`

**What I need is:**

Input: `I am new`
Output: `I ma wen`

Hope you understood what I meant here as I am quite new to programming and really need help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834885/how-to-print-an-array-backwards

Comment: the task is almost trivial if you store the words as `std::string`s, perhaps in a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print an array backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834885/how-to-print-an-array-backwards)

Comment: @Blaze its not a duplicate if I read the other quesiton correctly. Here OP does not want the whole array reversed but only the words within the string reversed (but order of the words unchanged)

Comment: Tip: Don't create arguments like `char m[50]` but instead use `char*` or, as this is C++ code, `const std::string&`.

Comment: @Eddie duplicate of [Turns all the char words in the opposite way using getline, array in c++
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816331/turns-all-the-char-words-in-the-opposite-way-using-getline-array-in-c/53816943#53816943)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a c++ solution then the following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "I am new";
    auto begin = str.begin();
    while (begin != str.end())
    {
        auto end = std::find(begin, str.end(), ' ');
        std::reverse(begin, end);
        if (end == str.end())
        {
            break;
        }
        begin = end + 1;
    }
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, although it would be great if it could be a bit simpler haha, I'll try to figure out how this fully works and implement it in my code, thanks!

Comment: @Eddie this is the simple way, working with char arrays is complicated :P

Comment: If by simpler you mean using `char` arrays then you can mostly use the same code just replace `std::string::find` with `strchr`. `std::reverse` will work with pointers as well as iterators.

Comment: In this case std::find makes things a little more compact

Answer (score 1):

Since not only a space may delimiter words also other whitespaces should be considered.

```
#include <iostream>

bool IsWhiteSpaceOrEnd(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
    case '\r':
    case '\n':
    case 0:
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void ReverseWord(char* begin, char* end) {
    --end;
    while (begin < end) {
        char temp = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = temp;
        ++begin;
        --end;
    }
}

void ReverseEachWord(char* str) {
    char* begin = str;
    while (0 != *begin) {
        char* end = begin + 1;
        // find next end of word
        while (!IsWhiteSpaceOrEnd(*end)) {
            ++end;
        }
        // reverse the word between begin and end
        ReverseWord(begin, end);
        begin = end;
        // go forward to the next begin of a word
        while ((0 != *begin) && IsWhiteSpaceOrEnd(*begin)) {
            ++begin;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* text = strdup("I am new");
    ReverseEachWord(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really understandable, although I'm making just a simple program, I'll keep this in mind for future!

Answer (score 1):

I'd convert the char array input and output to strings, at least for processing. You can convert the result back to char array if you really need that.

```
string ReverseText(const string& text)
{
    string word(""), result("");

    for (const auto& character : text)
    {
        if (!isspace(character))
            word += character;  // Build the next word to reverse
        else
        {
            std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end()); // Reverse the completed word
            result += word + character; // Add your processed word to the result
            word = "";  // Clear word variable for next iteration
        }
    }

    std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end()); // Don't forget the last word built
    return result + word;
}
```

Comment: I do need the char array, that's why I asked the question.